# Expressing Fourier Series Representation of $e^{j \beta \cos 2 \pi f_m t}$ in terms of Bessel's Function.

Tags: fourier-series, bessel-functions

I want to represent the signal $e^{j \beta \cos 2 \pi f_m t}$ in terms of its Fourier Series and then represent the result in terms of Bessel's Function. I have computed $c_n$ and would like someone to check if what I have done is correct or not. Thanks for helping.

[image]

[image]

[image]

$\newcommand{\Real}{\operatorname{Re}}\newcommand{\dd}{\; \mathrm{d}}$
\begin{align*}
c(t)&= A_c\cos (2\pi f_c t)\\
u(t)&= A_c\cos [2\pi f_c t + \beta \cos 2\pi f_c t]\\
u(t)&= \Real[A_c e^{j2\pi f_c t} e^{j \beta 2\pi f_c t}]
\end{align*}
Since $\cos 2\pi f_m t$ is periodic with period $T_m=\frac1{f_m}$, the same is true for complex exponential signal $e^{j \beta 2\pi f_m t}$. Therefore it can be represented as a Fourier series expansion.

Fourier series expansion is given by
$$x(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{j2\pi\frac{n}{T_0}t}$$
where $$c_n = \frac1{T_0}\int_{\alpha}^{\alpha+T_0} x(t) e^{-j2\pi\frac{n}{T_0}t} \dd t$$

\begin{align*}
c_n
&= \frac1{T_0}\int_0^{T_0} e^{j \beta \cos 2\pi f_c t} e^{-j2\pi\frac{n}{T_0}t} \dd t\\
&= \frac1{T_m}\int_0^{T_m} e^{j \beta \cos 2\pi f_c t} e^{-j2\pi\frac{n}{T_m}t} \dd t \\
&= f_m \int_0^{\frac1{f_m}} e^{j \beta \cos 2\pi f_c t} e^{-j2\pi f_mt}  \dd t \tag{i}
\end{align*}

Let $u=2\pi f_m t$, $\dd u=2\pi f_m \dd t$.
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
  t & 0 & 1/f_m \\
  u & 0 & 2\pi 
\end{array}
$$
$(i)$ becomes:
\begin{align*}
&= f_m \int_0^{2\pi} e^{j \beta \cos u} e^{-jun}  \frac{\dd u }{2\pi f_m}
&= \frac1{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{j \beta \cos u} e^{-jnu}  \dd u  \tag{ii}
\end{align*}
Now $\sin[\pi/2+u]=\cos u$. $(ii)$ becomes
$$=\frac1{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{j \beta \sin [u+\pi/2]} e^{-jnu}  \dd u  \tag{iii}$$
$\sin [u+\pi/2] = \sin u \cos\frac\pi2+\cos u\sin\frac\pi2=\cos u$

Let $\pi/2+u=z$, $\dd u=\dd z$, $u=z-\frac\pi2$
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
  u & 0 & 2\pi \\
  z & \pi/2 & 5\pi/2
\end{array}
$$
$(iii)$ Becomes
\begin{align*}
&=\frac1{2\pi} \int_{\frac\pi2}^{\frac{5\pi}2} e^{j \beta \sin z]} e^{-jn(z-\pi/2)}  \dd z \\
&=\frac1{2\pi} \int_{\frac\pi2}^{\frac{5\pi}2} e^{j \beta \sin z]} e^{-jnz+jn\pi/2}  \dd z \\
&=\frac1{2\pi} e^{jn\pi/2}\int_{\frac\pi2}^{\frac{5\pi}2} e^{j \beta \sin z]} e^{-jnz}  \dd z \\
&=\frac1{2\pi} e^{jn\pi/2}\int_{2\pi} e^{j \beta \sin z]} e^{-jnz}  \dd z \\
&=e^{jn\pi/2} J_n(\beta)
\end{align*}

Comment: It's the [Jacobi-Anger identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's still a mess after Martin's edit, but you're essentially right. Your notation is inconsistent. I'll try to summarise.

We have
$x(t) = e^{j\beta \cos (2\pi ft)}$. By a change of variables $\tilde t = 2\pi f t$, we can assume that $f = \frac1{2\pi}$ and $T=2\pi $, so we are tasked with computing
$$ c_n :=\frac1{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{j\beta \cos t} e^{-jnt} \, dt.$$
We seem to be happy with accepting the definition of the Bessel functions $J_n(\beta)$ as
$$ J_n(\beta) := \frac1{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{j\beta \sin t} e^{-jnt} \, dt.$$
Since $\cos t = \sin(t+\pi/2)$, changing variables $\tau = t+\pi /2$ gives
$$ c_n = \frac1{2\pi} \int_{\pi/2}^{5\pi/2} e^{j\beta \sin \tau} e^{-jn(\tau - \pi/2)} \, d\tau = e^{jn\pi/2}\frac1{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{j\beta \sin \tau} e^{-jn\tau} \, d\tau $$
where we used the fact that the integrand is periodic. By the way, 
$$e^{jn\pi/2}=i^n$$
this gives the formula in the [Wikipedia page (Jacobi-Anger identity)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion) linked in the above comment.

Comment: Sorry for making a mess in my edit. (I did try to faithfully represent what was handwritten, but it is quite likely that I failed.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak no need to apologise, I meant no slight to you, and only a few typos remain. There's only so much mathjax can do

Comment: @CalvinKhor Actually I was not able to understand  how $ c_n = \frac1{2\pi} \int_{\pi/2}^{5\pi/2} e^{j\beta \sin \tau} e^{-jn(\tau - \pi/2)} \, d\tau = e^{jn\pi/2}\frac1{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{j\beta \sin \tau} e^{-jn\tau} \, d\tau $. Now that you have mentioned that the integrand is periodic, it all makes sense. If you click on the pictures it is easier to view the work out.

Comment: Glad to help @Soumee :) for completeness when a function $F:\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$ is $2\pi$-periodic we have: $$ \int_{2\pi}^{5\pi/2} F dt= \int_0^{\pi/2} F dt$$ which lets you rewrite as above.